# Substitute a regular expression with arguments

Tags: unix, sed, grep

I need to substitute in many files an expression, like

```
@$%arg1
```

with

```
func(arg1)
```

with `sed` or `grep` or another command line tools Unix-like.
Thank you.

Comment: Where you need to substitute the value of variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is the exact expression, then you can use

```
sed 's/#@$%arg1/func(arg1)/g' file1 file2
```

If arg1 is variable, try this:

```
sed 's/#@$%\(\w\+\)/func(\1)/g' file1 file2
```